# How to trigger go to line number action programmatically in Monaco Editor Command Palette?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I know i can trigger the Command Palette programmatically through [this way](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/193#issuecomment-248222607):

```js
editor.trigger('anyString', 'editor.action.quickCommand')
```

However how do i trigger the "go to line number" action programmatically, which its related shortcut key is `Ctrl + G`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally tested and found the solution:

```js
editor.focus()
editor.trigger('whatever', 'editor.action.gotoLine')
```

ref: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/4bf3b49c41c7d1612f76608d60f946b26d835095/build/releaseMetadata.ts